# Can the body be trained to perform best at unusual times of day?

Tags: cycling, performance, triathlon

It's known that athletes perform best at certain times of day - most studies suggest that late afternoon / early evening seems to be the best time for peak performance. See [this](https://www.nhs.uk/news/lifestyle-and-exercise/body-clock-may-have-effect-on-sporting-peak-performance/) link for an article about this.

Can a body be trained to overcome its natural circadian rhythm and perform best at (say) 3 o'clock in the morning?

Let's say you have an endurance sporting event that has to take place in the early hours - maybe it requires public roads to be closed, or maybe it's dependent on the time of day for some other reason.

I'd guess that training at 3am would help for an event that will be taking place at 3am, but is there any science to back up my guess? Has anyone published any studies on this?